# How to use Pattern Matching where clause in Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have this Flink program below:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

val dataStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](topicChannel1, new SimpleStringSchema(), props))

val partitionedInput = dataStream.keyBy(jsonString => {
  val jsonParser = new JsonParser()
  val jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject()
  jsonObject.get("account")
})

val pattern = Pattern.begin[String]("start").where(jsonString => 
            val jsonParser = new JsonParser()
            val jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject()
            jsonObject.get("account") == "iOS") //ERROR HERE

val patternStream = CEP.pattern(partitionedInput, pattern)
```

I am getting an error at the `val pattern = ...` line saying `Expected IterativeCondition[String], actual: (Nothing) => Unit`.

My `dataStream` consists of JSON objects which I parse in the `keyBy` to key by the account key inside the JSON object. Then I am trying to create a pattern but I am getting an error when creating the pattern.

Comment: What is the function you apply in `where(jsonString => ...)`?

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz I have updated the code above of what function I want to apply in the where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the proper API. For scala you should import

```
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.pattern.Pattern
```

rather than

```
import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please take a look at another question I had regarding this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965109/nothing-is-being-printed-out-from-a-flink-patterned-stream