# Nothing is being printed out from a Flink Patterned Stream

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have this code below:

```
import java.util.Properties

import com.google.gson._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.pattern.Pattern
import org.apache.flink.cep.scala.CEP
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema

object WindowedWordCount {
  val configFactory = ConfigFactory.load()
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val brokers = configFactory.getString("kafka.broker")
    val topicChannel1 = configFactory.getString("kafka.topic1")

    val props = new Properties()
    ...

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

    val dataStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](topicChannel1, new SimpleStringSchema(), props))

    val partitionedInput = dataStream.keyBy(jsonString => {
      val jsonParser = new JsonParser()
      val jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject()
      jsonObject.get("account")
    })

    val priceCheck = Pattern.begin[String]("start").where({jsonString =>
      val jsonParser = new JsonParser()
      val jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject()
      jsonObject.get("account").toString == "iOS"})

    val pattern = CEP.pattern(partitionedInput, priceCheck)

    val newStream = pattern.select(x =>
      x.get("start").map({str =>
        str
      })
    )

    newStream.print()

    env.execute()
  }
}
```

For some reason in the above code at the `newStream.print()` nothing is being printed out. I am positive that there is data in Kafka that matches the pattern that I defined above but for some reason nothing is being printed out.

Can anyone please help me spot an error in this code?

**EDIT:**

```
class TimestampExtractor extends AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks[String] with Serializable {

  override def extractTimestamp(e: String, prevElementTimestamp: Long) = {
    val jsonParser = new JsonParser()
    val context = jsonParser.parse(e).getAsJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("context")
    Instant.parse(context.get("serverTimestamp").toString.replaceAll("\"", "")).toEpochMilli
  }

  override def getCurrentWatermark(): Watermark = {
    new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis())
  }
}
```

I saw on the flink doc that you can just return `prevElementTimestamp` in the `extractTimestamp` method (if you are using Kafka010) and `new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis)` in the `getCurrentWatermark` method.

But I don't understand what `prevElementTimestamp` is or why one would return `new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis)` as the WaterMark and not something else. Can you please elaborate on why we do this on how `WaterMark` and `EventTime` work together please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do setup your job to work in `EventTime`, but you do not provide  timestamp and watermark extractor.

For more on working in event time see those [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#timestamp-assigners--watermark-generators). If you want to use the kafka embedded timestamps this [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/kafka.html#using-kafka-timestamps-and-flink-event-time-in-kafka-010) may help you.

In `EventTime` the CEP library buffers events upon watermark arrival so to properly handle out-of-order events. In your case there are no watermarks generated, so the events are buffered infinitly.

---

Edit:

1. For the `prevElementTimestamp` I think the docs are pretty clear:

   > There is no need to define a timestamp extractor when using the timestamps from Kafka. The previousElementTimestamp argument of the extractTimestamp() method **contains the timestamp carried by the Kafka message**.

   Since Kafka 0.10.x Kafka messages can have embedded timestamp.
2. Generating `Watermark` as `new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis)` in this case is not a good idea. You should create `Watermark` based on your knowledge of the data. For information on how `Watermark` and `EventTime` work together I could not be more clear than the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/event_time.html#event-time)

Comment: I have added an edit to my post. Can you please take a look at it?